# Excel VLOOKUP between two columns of words

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two columns of words (Old list) and (New list)
I'm trying to check using the `VLOOKUP()` function both columns and find which words of the New list doesn't appear in the Old list.

[image]

(The answers here is obviously: eyes, john, martha, phone)

I'm giving this simple example to know what `VLOOKUP()` formula to also apply to a larger sample. In reality I have two columns of over 1000 items. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=FILTER(F2:F10, ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F10,A2:A10,1,FALSE)))

This will filter it down and remove all the N/A values while comparing the 2nd list to the first.

[image]

EDIT:
as per comment needing clarification (too long to put as a comment)

You can do anything you’d like by substituting references. It’s best to think of the syntax of things here to get a lay of the land and figure out what you want to pull information from.

The ISNA() just handles N/A errors that will occur with partial lists and is irrelevant to understanding where to put your references.

```
=filter(array, include, [if_empty])
```

Where “array” is the range you want to filter FROM
And “include” is what you are searching FOR from that range.
The [if_empty] is optional – you can put a text there, like “No Results” in quotes so that it’ll substitute that for N/A.

The “include” portion is where I’ve added additional information because I want to narrow in what I’m including…. In the plain and simple form of =filter() you’d just be putting a word/cell reference you’re looking for. It’ll pull every column for the whole table if there are multiple columns. But we want it to search multiple criteria simultaneously.

```
=vlookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num,range_lookup)
```

what you are searching FOR (in this case anything within the table), where you want to look for it (where you are searching FROM), which column to find it in (column 1 in your case), and TRUE/FALSE – exact or approximate matches.

The easiest way to search across multiple sheets is to have the files open, and as you type in the formula bar when you get to each section click and highlight what you want by switching sheets (alt tab). Just pay really close attention to searching FOR versus searching FROM and you can do any combination of comparison you need.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! What would you do if they were both in separate files?

For example Old List in file1.xlsx and newlist in file2.xlsx

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Working from "new list" in it's own file I was able to do the same thing, except adjusting the file references accordingly: 
=FILTER(A2:A10,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10,[oldlist.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,1,FALSE)))

Please accept this as an answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Is there a way to lookup a value from other worksheet in a column in my current worksheet? The other way around.

Comment: For example, =FILTER(A2:A10,ISNA(VLOOKUP([oldlist.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,A2:A10,1,FALSE)))

Comment: Updated and edited for clarification for you on how to get the right references!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like TRUE/FALSE for each element you can use the following

=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,ColumnToSearch,0))

Comment: Not wrong however it should be noted in this case that `A1` refers to the first value of the New List (in this case, assuming `F2`), and if you start getting errors make sure the `ColumnToSearch` has its cell references locked (ex. `A2:10` becomes `$A$2:$A$10`)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).